# Minecraft not working on Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc

I tried to launch Minecraft on the new launcher and it doesn't seem to work. It just shows that an unexpected error occured and I can not figure out how to access the console on this new launcher. I thought maybe it's because my PC user account name has the letter "ė" in it and I thought maybe Minecraft doesn't support it. I tried changing the .minecraft folder location but that did not help or I did it wrong. Then I tried using compatibility mode for Windows 7 and that did not help either.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this and what to try? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What console do you mean? Are you trying to run a server?

Comment: The launcher console that used to be accessible before. It shows errors when launching minecraft and how it's initializing. I can't find that type of game console on this launcher. I am not talking about a server.

Comment: Ah, so you mean the game log. I currently can't really check, but is there an option in the advanced profile settings to keep the launcher open while playing?

Comment: Yes there is. I've also found out how to open the game output. It seems like it dies at "Installing versions!". It makes me think that it truly is something with the path to the versions folder or something. It's kinda weird that it would just crash like that. Minecraft doesn't even launch. But what I found even stranger is that it does download the file. I checked the versions folder and 1.12 is there. I went inside there and there are files in there. What is going on here?

Comment: So the game windows doesn't even open (showing the Mojang logo)? Do you get a game output or even a crash log?

Comment: Nope, doesn't launch at ALL. I found a crash log and there is the good ol' "Can't find main.Main class" error. This is leading me towards the fix since I do remember this error because it happened SO many times while I was making plugins and mods. But, if you are interested in the log: https://pastebin.com/2i8bmCuR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours upon hours of digging I realized that my log files and all files in general seemed oddly placed. Turns out that my directories were indeed the things that kept me from launching the game. I searched a bit more and turns out there is an easy fix. I downloaded MultiMC which made it's own directories bypassing the PC username that had weird letters. I placed it in the C: disk and sure enough, the game works! Thank you, Fabian, for trying to help. You lead me on a path towards the fix.

Comment: Great! Can you now please mark your own answer as accepted? That way this question gets sort of marked as answered successfully.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours. I can't mark my own answer as correct straight away.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: Btw, you can mark it as accepted now.